# Generate specific date in bash

Tags: bash, shell, date, random

Hi I have written down some bash to generate the date in format YYYYDDMM.

I know that is not perfect but the final thing will be:

**Generate a range of 2 dates that are 31 days apart from each other and start with a minimum of today + one day and the older ones end at the end of this year. In format YYYYMMDD**

```bash
month="$(awk -v min=1 -v max=12 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}')"
day="$(awk -v min=1 -v max=31 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}')"
year="$(date +%Y)"



if (( "${month}" < 10 )); then
    month_proper="$(echo 0"${month}")"
else
month_proper="$(echo "${month}")"
fi
if (( "${day}" < 10 )); then
    day_proper="$(echo 0"${day}")"

else
day_proper="$(echo "${day}")"
fi



echo month "${month}"
echo month with 0 if smaller than 10 : "${month_proper}"
echo day "${day}"
echo day with 0 smaller than 10 : "${day_proper}"

ok="$(date -d ""$year""${month_proper}""${day_proper}"" +"%Y%m%d")"
echo date with proper format "${ok}"
date -d "$year""${month_proper}""${day_proper}"
```

In which direction would I have to expand this script to get the final result? I already have the date generation, but there is no checking if there is one day ahead of today.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Do you want every pair, a random pair, or what? What is the desired output of the script exactly?

Comment: `month=$(($RANDOM % 12 + 1))` (and similar for `day`) is probably sufficiently random without needing to use `awk`.

Comment: Requested range is always `YYYY1231`..`yyyy0131`, isn't it?  You have just to deal with the situation when "today" is Dec-31.

Comment: Rather than generating months and days, just find the number of days until Dec 1, pick a random number between 1 and that, and then format it as a date with GNU's `date -d "today + 42 days"`. Automatically handles leap years and everything.

Comment: Yes I need random dates  with above requirements

Answer (score 0):

Requirements specify range nearly exactly (it is Dec-31 till Jan-31 next year), so you can write

```
a_fmt=`date -d "tomorrow" +%Y1231`
a_num=`date -d "$a_fmt" +%s`

b_num=$(( a_num + 31 * 24 * 3600 ))
b_fmt=`date -d @$b_num +%Y%m%d`

echo "Range is '$a_fmt'..'$b_fmt'"
```